# sed backslashes

Tags: url, sed

I have the following. I am replacing some fields in html with values from a carat delimited text file.

```
while  IFS=^ read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
do
    echo $col1
      echo "HtmlFor$col1" >> "SiteHtml.txt"
      cat $FILENAME1 | sed  "s/var1/$col1/" | sed  "s/var2/$col2/"| sed  "s/var3/$col3/" | sed  "s/var4/$col4/" | sed  "s/var5/$col5/" >> "SiteHtml.txt"
      # | sed  "s/var3/$col3/" | sed  "s/var4/$col4/" | sed  "s/var5/$col5/" | sed  "s/var6/$col6/"
done
```

if there is a backslash in the column I get an error. if i try to escape them with "/" I still get an error. It only works if I remove them, which I cant do. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use 3 backslashes to replace a single backslash in 'sed'.

Example:

```
echo "\\" | sed "s/\\\/replace/"
```

The reason for that is: The first \ escapes the second \ while getting passed as an argument and once passed inside the binary argument will be something like "s/\/replace" and now when the program parses the string the second \ escapes the third \ to finally get the string to be replaced as '\'.

There can be many things going wrong as \ can get escaped. One of these things might be bothering you.

1. Your '\' is next to **c,n** or any other special character that has meaning when we use it in a string
2. You '\' is the last character of the string **$col1** variable which is getting ignored of it's meaning when the sed is parsing the string.

I cannot say much without seeing the HTML being parsed.

**Note:** These are not the only things that might give you an error, but you have a general idea how backslashes affect string parsing in sed and hopefully you can figure out the solution.

**PS:** Hope you also know that anything passed between double quotes gets substituted by the value by the shell before passing it as an argument, whereas anything being passed between single quotes does not get substituted by its value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version:

```
echo "\\" | sed "s [\] replace "
```